# Is GH Copilot included in Visual Studio Enterprise edition with no additional charge

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I have updated Visual Studio Enterprise edition to the latest version: 17.9.1. Installed copilot, and restarted Visual Studio with an existing solution that's in our private azure git repo.  But I am getting this error with the copilot icon in the left bottom corner disabled in the IDE:

`Copilot in Visual Studio Enterprise edition does not work with a message: GitHub Copilot is disabled due to an error: Request checkStatus failed with message: Response content-type is text/xml, charset=Utf-8 (status=403)`

My questions here are:

1. What caused the 403 error? Unable to connect to my company's private repo? If so, what do I need to do to enable it?
2. Is GH Copilot come with Visual Studio Enterprise edition with no additional charge?

Comment: Edited title, and the 2nd question is invalid, as the info on Copilot is included in Visual Studio Enterprise edition with no additional charge is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we need either to have a GitHub Copilot Individual subscription or Copilot Business or GitHub Copilot Enterprise license.

GitHub Copilot isn't included with VS Enterprise edition.

see reference on copilot billing: https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-copilot/about-billing-for-github-copilot